# Good use of content profile

Tags: users

I am using Drupal 6 and I have installed the [Content Profile](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile) module.
First I made 3 extra fields, "gender," "seeking gender," and "dob." Now I want to create a multistep that users needs to fill in with other details.

I was wondering how I can do this using content profile module. I have read that this is a very good module in order to customizing user profiles.

Answer (score 1):

One of the only ways I have been successful at making required multistep forms before having access to the website was using CTools to construct the form workflow, and submitting the data on submit callbacks into Drupal with [node_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_save/6).

See [Intro to Drupal 6 Multistep Form Domination Using Chaos Tools](http://www.nicklewis.org/using-chaos-tools-form-wizard-build-multistep-forms-drupal-6).